# jQuery UI dialog is not a function when re-calling it

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, dialog

I have this function to open a jQuery UI dialog:

```
function pop_up(div, titulo) {
  $("#" + div).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "explode",
    hide: "explode",
    modal: true,
    minHeight: 550,
    height: "auto",
    width: "auto",
    title: titulo,
  });

  $("#" + div).dialog("open");

  return false;
}
```

which I call in the same hidden div:

```
pop_up('pop', 'my title');
```

Which works fine (I can open and close as many times as I want) but if I load some content dynamically in the #div I get this firebug error (in the next attempt to open a dialog)

```
$("#" + div).dialog is not a function
[Parar en este error]   

title: titulo
```

Basically

```
pop_up('pop', 'my title');   /* OK */

$('#pop').load('somefile.html',function(){
    pop_up('pop', 'some title');   /* CRASH */
});
```

will fire the error; any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's a timing issue and that the load manages to finish prior to the function call that created the dialog?

Comment: @j08691 but its a bit weird that the error is not a function, then. no?

Comment: Hmmm, seems to work on in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wt9UB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you are calling `pop_up()` with an id of **div**.  I'm not sure that is a good id value, but just the same in the next line of code you try to load 'somefile.html' into **#pop** which may have not been created yet.  Then you try to create a new `pop_up` which is referencing the same object that is being loaded (**#pop**).

Would this work?

```
pop_up('div1', 'my title');
$('#div1').load('somefile.html',function(){
    pop_up('pop', 'some title');
});
```

Here we use a dialog with an id of **div1**.  Then we load 'somefile.html' into that dialog.  Once that load is completed, we create a new `pop_up` called **pop**.

Hope this helps!